# WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER When I send a control command to the card reader

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I call the verify() method to read the PIN from a card reader (omnikey 3821) but I i have the following exception:

WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

I think the problem is the second parameter of the method transmitControlCommand that throws the following error:

```
    javax.smartcardio.CardException: transmitControlCommand() failed
        at sun.security.smartcardio.CardImpl.transmitControlCommand(Unknown Source)
        at adminServ.Transaction.verify(Transaction.java:34)
        at adminServ.Transaction.venteMenu(Transaction.java:160)
        at adminServ.SampleClient.main(SampleClient.java:541)
    Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
        at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardControl(Native Method)
        ... 4 more
    transmitControlCommand() failed.
```

My code:

```
    /* la méthode verify() */
        private  void verify() throws CadTransportException,IOException, CardException, PCSCException
            {
                byte[] PIN_VERIFY = super.createPINVerifyStructure();
                byte [] rep= super.c.transmitControlCommand(3223564, PIN_VERIFY);
            }

/* la méthode createPINVerifyStructure() */

protected static byte[] createPINVerifyStructure() {  

         // VerifyAPDUSpec apduSpec = new VerifyAPDUSpec(
    byte[] apdu = new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF };

    // 1, VerifyAPDUSpec.PIN_FORMAT_BCD, 7, 4, 4);

    ByteArrayOutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    s.write(bTimeOut);
    s.write(bTimeOut2);
    s.write(0x82);
    s.write(0x04);
    s.write(0x00);      
    s.write(wPINMaxExtraDigitMax); // max PIN length
    s.write(wPINMaxExtraDigitMin); // min PIN length
    s.write(bEntryValidationCondition);
    // bNumberMessage
    s.write(0x01);
    // wLangId [0x04 0x09 english, little endian]
    s.write(0x04);
    s.write(0x09);
    // bMsgIndex
    s.write(0x01);
    // bTeoPrologue
    s.write(0x00);
    s.write(0x00);
    s.write(0x00);
    // ulDataLength
    s.write(apdu.length);
    s.write(0x00);
    s.write(0x00);
    s.write(0x00);
    // abData
    try {
        s.write(apdu);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // As we are dealing with ByteArrayOutputStreams no exception is to
        // be
        // expected.
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return s.toByteArray();
    }
```

please help .